C++: Understanding `int&...` usage in a template class constructor's template argument
I found an example in some source code which contains int&... like below (line 1):
template <typename Char>
struct A {
 public:
  template <int&..., size_t N> // Line 1
  // template <size_t N>       // Line 2
  constexpr A(const Char (&arr)[N]) noexcept
      : ptr_(arr), len_(std::char_traits<Char>::length(arr)) {}

  const Char* c_str() const noexcept { return ptr_; }

 private:
  const Char* ptr_ = nullptr;
  size_t len_ = 0;
};

using AChar = A<char>;

template <typename Char, typename Traits>
std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits>& operator<<(
    std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits>& os,
    A<Char> view) {
  return os << view.c_str();
}

I am trying to understand usage of A where the int&... is useful.
In both versions of above (Line 1 or Line 2) the following compile:
int main() {
  constexpr auto a = A{"hello"};
  static constexpr char kArr[] = "hell";
  constexpr auto a1 = A{kArr};
  constexpr A a2{"hello"};
  constexpr A a3{kArr};

  std::cout << a << '\n';
  std::cout << a1 << '\n';
  std::cout << a2 << '\n';
  std::cout << a3 << '\n';
}

This, this and this post in stackoverflow talk about 'ExplicitArgumentBarrier'. The examples over there deal with template functions.
template <int&... ExplicitArgumentBarrier, typename T>
void AcceptSomeReference(const T&) {}

Will cause the following to fail:
AcceptSomeReference<char>('c'); 

How can such "explicit" specification attempt be made for class A which is being prevented by int&...?

Might be that it was copied from a factory method (as in line marked 3 in this example). Seems that for a constructor this doesn't have any effect, as template parameters of a constructor cannot be explicitly specified because constructors are called without using a function name.

Is this intentionally tagged C++11 ? As in, specifically excluding C++17 Class Template Argument Deduction?
